# when I try to put an 'X' letter in button, it slightly goes down, CSS and React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

So, I'm basically trying to do a TicTacToe game on React, and I've managed to create squares but when I click one of them, the square goes a little bit down, why?

[image]

```
.square {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  margin: 2px;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

And one more thing, in my VsCode, React components doesn't automatically close, it stays like   but, I want it to be  when I save.

Comment: Instead of uploading an image create a fiddle that replicates the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.square`.

The `display` of `button`s are default `inline-block`, and the `vertical-align` is set to `baseline`.

When there are empty ones and one with content, the content(which is the character `x`) will automatically align to the baseline of the rest - and since others are empty, it'll align to the bottom of their box.

You can solve this problem by adding `vertical-align: top` to the buttons:

```css
.square {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  margin: 2px;
}

.row-2 .square {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<h2>Before</h2>
<div class="row">
  <button class="square"></button>
  <button class="square">x</button>
  <button class="square"></button>
</div>

<h2>After</h2>
<div class="row-2">
  <button class="square"></button>
  <button class="square">x</button>
  <button class="square"></button>
</div>
```